# Error code: must have identical levels in the same order

Tags: r, glm, multivariate-testing

When running the MCMCglmm function I get the following error message:

> fit_mcmc <- MCMCglmm(exchange ~ assocSRI,random=~mm(ID1 + ID2), data=within_dyad)
> Error in buildZ(rmodel.terms[r], data = data, nginverse = names(ginverse)) :
> terms involved in mm/str structures must have identical levels in the same order

All of the terms have the same number of levels, so I'm just not sure how to rectify the issue. I have 41 "obs" of 6 variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order the levels before you fire up the MCMCglmm command. One way to do this would be:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(within_dyad)
within_dyad <- within_dyad[order(level),]

#replace name of the level variable appropriately, then run the MCMCglmm command.
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I appreciate your help though! Do you know of any other fixes that might help?

Comment: @EmmaChereskin can you provide an example of the data?

Comment: 'data.frame': 41 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ ID1     : chr  "CEB" "CEB" "DEE" "BIG" ...
 $ ID2     : chr  "DEE" "DNG" "DNG" "FRE" ...
 $ assocSRI: num  0.389 0.176 0.264 0.596 0.346 ...
 $ vocalSRI: num  0.0104 0.0606 0.0256 0 0.0125 ...
 $ alliance: chr  "KS" "KS" "KS" "PD" ...
 $ exchange: int  0 6 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 ...